# Date comparison between 2 variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I am new to Postgres and I am currently figuring out how the date domains work.

I have a "Packages" table which has information of the name(text domain), start and end date(date domain i.e start = 2021-03-12, end = 2021-04-12) of the packages on sale.

I am trying to filter for packages which are currently on sale (relevant to today's date)

Am I able to compare date variables as such?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Packages P  
WHERE ((CURRENT_DATE >= P.start_date) AND (CURRENT_DATE <= P.end_date));
```

Comment: Yes that works. Why don't you simple try it? If you don't have local installation you could use https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html

Comment: Or you could simplify to `WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN P.start_date AND p.end_date`